# onIconPress Input component in react native doesn't work

Tags: javascript, react-native

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK4gw.png)

I need to make onPress event on icon rendered on Input but it doesn't seem to work, I did test with TextInput component but with no chance..

---

here's the code:

```
import {Button, Text, Icon, Layout, Input} from '@ui-kitten/components';

const renderIcon = (style) => (
 <Icon {...style} name={secureTextEntry ? 'eye-off' : 'eye'}/>
);

<Input
 style={{backgroundColor:"transparent", marginBottom:10}}
 label={{}}
 labelStyle={{textAlign: state.language.direction}}
 textStyle={{textAlign: state.language.direction}}
 size="small"
 onChangeText={{}
 secureTextEntry={true}
 icon={renderIcon}
  onIconPress={() => {console.log("Hey")}}
/>
```

Comment: Please post your code here as text.

Comment: Could you please explain what is this Input Component you're using?

Comment: thank u sir, sorry i took a lot of time to be able to publish ma first answer here:
import {Button, Text, Icon, Layout, Input} from '@ui-kitten/components';
const renderIcon = (style) => (
 <Icon {...style} name={secureTextEntry ? 'eye-off' : 'eye'}/>
);

<Input
 style={{backgroundColor:"transparent", marginBottom:10}}
 label={{}}
 labelStyle={{textAlign: state.language.direction}}
 textStyle={{textAlign: state.language.direction}}
 size="small"
 onChangeText={{}
 secureTextEntry={true}
 icon={renderIcon}
  onIconPress={() => {console.log("Hey")}}
/>